# Http connection getInputStream null pointer exception android

Tags: android, http, url, exception, https

I'm getting null pointer exception on method getInputStream() and I know that urlConnection isn't null

```
URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        /** Creating an http connection to communcate with url */
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        /** Connecting to url */
        urlConnection.connect();

        /** Reading data from url */
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Url string is fine I'm checking it in my browser.
Thank you.

Comment: So you openConnection is failing.  Why not print out your strUrl, make certain it is fine, probably do the log, and then check that urlConnection isn't null before going on.

Comment: Url string is fine. I got this while debugging http://pokit.org/get/?d8420f32feea9b81d6270b1468bd2bb6.jpg

Comment: It would help us answering your question if you could clarify the value of strURL

Comment: I'm accessing google place photo and url string goes like thishttps://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?&key=MY_KEY&photoreference and other parameters. It is fine, when i paste it in browser it gives me photo

Comment: Put a try..catch block around this and print out the stack trace to see where the problem actually happens.

Comment: I expect your problem is with your second connect. comment that out and see what happens.

Comment: This is stack trace http://pokit.org/get/?945ae32c1c8e5f7a393b06ae806481b8.jpg

Comment: I think I found an answer. "The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread." I should probably create a new thread and do this in it.